# Is it possible to check the pdf document version in jquery php?

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, mpdf

I am using mpdf for converting PDF. In the merging time any other PDF like greater than 1.4 version found the error is display like this:

> pdf unable to find the xref auto detect line ending the solution finding

So is it possible to control the user on the front end to upload the supported format to merging the PDF file?

Comment: Directly, no. The file has to be validated by the server. So upload, check and return a validation boolean.

Comment: i want to fix this problem but user can upload any version of pdf ,on merging its error came ,if i remove that pdf correctly working .

Comment: Than check the version number when the client upload is successful. Return either true or false if the versioning does not match.

Comment: The version number claimed in the PDF metadata generally has nothing to do with what features of PDF are being used in the document. You should not count on it being accurate.

Comment: then how to merge the higher pdf version its not supporting in mpdf